Black and white horror movie I saw as a child late 60's early 70's, IIRC
I remember a scene with a nurse taking care of someone, I think it was an elderly man, and she had to leave. 
It was around dusk and she had to cross a bog/field/creepy something. The people (may have been the son and daughter of the sick man) asked her to stay at the house as it was OK but the nurse left anyway.
Something chased her and killed her. I remember the 'monster' was wearing something black with silvery somethings and would wiggle her fingers in her victims face to put a spell on them or something. I think it involved cats.
There was a scene with a dead black cat, I think, can't remember the connection to the 'monster' though.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.
